# Self learning Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, self-learning

My job has recently started to involve a lot more cryptography.  I would like to be become more familiar with the mathematics behind it, and so I would like to learn the basics of group theory.

Please can anyone recommend any good resources (preferably books!) for someone who is self learning this subject.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: The best book for you is very dependent on your background but with that being said, Pinter's book on abstract algebra was very good for self study. It's also very cheap so I would recommend that.

Comment: Got it - I'll check out Pinter's book - thanks for the recommendation!